# Python Load module in parent to prevent overwrite problems

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qgis

I'm building a QGIS plugin with Python and designed a GUI for it. I can compile it with pyuic4, but on load it gives an error. I found out that I can prevent that error by adding the line below in the compiled Python code. Only at some moments I have to recompile and so the file gets overwritten and the line is lost.

form.py

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerComboBox
```

I have a 'parent' file which imports the compiled version like so:

dialog.py

```
from form import Ui_Dialog
```

Is there some way to import the QgsMapLayerComboBox in dialog.py so I don't have to add it every time to form.py after I recompiled my GUI?

EDIT:

```
<widget class="QgsMapLayerComboBox" name="mMapLayerComboBox">
 <property name="geometry">
  <rect>
   <x>100</x>
   <y>18</y>
   <width>160</width>
   <height>22</height>
  </rect>
 </property>
 <property name="filters">
  <set>QgsMapLayerProxyModel::RasterLayer</set>
 </property>
</widget>
</widget>
<customwidgets>
<customwidget>
 <class>QgsMapLayerComboBox</class>
 <extends>QComboBox</extends>
 <header>qgsmaplayercombobox.h</header>
</customwidget>
</customwidgets>
```

Comment: I design a GUI with Qt Designer which comes installed with QGIS. The save file is a XML. So when I make changes to my GUI design I get a new XML. To be able to use it I have to 'compile' it (better choice of words would probably have been 'convert') with pyuic4 from XML to Python code.

Comment: Can you provide a **minimalistic** XML file that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @three_pineapples I edited my question and added a part of the XML. It is a custom widget meant to be used in QGIS. You think about a way that the needed import gets automatically added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your form.ui with some text editor and replace:

```
<customwidget>
 <class>QgsMapLayerComboBox</class>
 <extends>QComboBox</extends>
 <header>qgsmaplayercombobox.h</header>
</customwidget>
```

with

```
<customwidget>
 <class>QgsMapLayerComboBox</class>
 <extends>QComboBox</extends>
 <header>qgis.gui</header>
</customwidget>
```

and compile again.